# Ambient color of material

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

When selecting the color of a material, I have the option to change diffuse and specular color. Where do I change the ambient color?

When I export to .obj/.mtl, I get `Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000`, which I then need to adjust manually.

How can I set this value in Blender?

According to phong model, every object has ambient, diffuse, and specular color. That's why exporting to .obj/.mtl has Ka Kd Ks elements. However, in blender I can only set specular and diffuse color. How can I set ambient color resulting non-zero values of Ka after exporting to .obj/.mtl?

Comment: Ambient color? Under the *world settings* you can change that, but I don't know that it exports . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise it does.